# I want to see a page dated in Dec 2012, how to I do it?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

This is Google's cache of http://www.seab.gov.sg/. It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on 15 Jan 2013 05:31:28 GMT. The current page could have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can’t see older caches on Google, but you could try searching for it on [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/web.php).

For that particular page though, there is [no available archive for December](http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.seab.gov.sg/).