# How can I recover a cached page that was deleted?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to see a page dated in Dec 2012, how to I do it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39485/i-want-to-see-a-page-dated-in-dec-2012-how-to-i-do-it)

Here is a cached version from January 16, 2013.  I need a cached version from December 2012.  Is there a way to modify the URL to bring up a cached version from December 2012?

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&q=cache%3Awww.youngsopianostudio.com%3A&btnG=

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I searched forums and sites but didn't find any parameters for URL to see a cache of specific date. What I learned is that Google only keeps the last cached page.